# Is there a way of dynamically changing the email template subject field on SES templates?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, email-templates

I am currently using SES to store email templates with serverless-ses-template on deployment. 
The templates get stored with the following parameters, both of which are mandatory:

```
templateId: 'status-template',
templateSubject: 'Some Title'
```

In my Lambda, I get the template I need, I map the values to the template and send it:

```
const email = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: targetAddresses
        },
        Source: 'sourcemail@mail.com',
        Template: "status-template",
        TemplateData: JSON.stringify(templateData)
    };

await ses.sendTemplatedEmail(email).promise();
```

Once this email is recieved, the subject is expectedly "Some Title" as in the template. 
Is there a way of dynamically changing that title before sending it i.e. changing the title from "Some Title" to "Other Title"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize your subject and pretty much any other field, by creating what is essentially a custom field value and wrapping it in double curly brackets, like so:

`templateSubject: "Important Message for {{ username }}"`

Then add your "username" parameter to your `templateData` object, and when the email is delivered it will replace the {{ username }} with the value, in this case "Marko Nikolov".

```
const templateData = {
    "username": "Marko Nikolov"
};

const email = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: targetAddresses
        },
        Source: 'sourcemail@mail.com',
        Template: "status-template",
        TemplateData: JSON.stringify(templateData),
    };

await ses.sendTemplatedEmail(email).promise();
```

You can read more about the sendTemplatedEmail property in the API docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#sendTemplatedEmail-property), and creating and customizing SES email templates [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#createTemplate-property).

Comment: Exactly what I needed.
Thank you.